# Remote postgres database on Heroku app

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, amazon-ec2

How can i connect my Heroku app to a Postgres database hosted on amazon EC2 without any paid addon?
I am using Django and my current code is:

`DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://postgres:xxx@publicip/dbname')}`

but i am still getting connected to my local database instead..

Comment: For some platforms Heroku seems to override the usual connection configuration and inject its own config. You may need to look up Heroku-specific documentation on Django to see how it configures connections in Django.

Comment: ill try reading the documentation thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application is likely connecting to a free Postgres database as defined by the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable. You should use `config:set` to set that variable to point to your remote database, and ensure your code connects to that `DATABASE_URL`:

```
$ heroku config:set DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:xxx@publicip/dbname --app your_app
```

See also:

- [Getting Started with Django on Heroku:Django settings](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django#django-settings)